# how to save information in iphone app without using database

Tags: ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have an app in iPhone. When user open my app first time I want to get his name and save it. And I want to retrieve this name later to use else where. How to do this?

Comment: Post your code .. this is not write my code for me site!!

Comment: I mean have you implemented something? if yes then post your code

Comment: as i am sharing my score on fb .. i want a copy of high score in my game so next time when player share his score on fb he knw before its his high score or not ...
- (void) facebookAgent:(FacebookAgent*)agent requestFaild:(NSString*) message{
 self.fbAgent.shouldResumeSession =NO;
 [self.fbAgent setStatus:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I Just Made %d Score", scores+bonuses]]; 
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[NSUserDefault](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) is your friend...

```
//To save name
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setObject:@"TextToSave" forKey:@"keyToLookupString"];

//retrieving
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *myString = [prefs stringForKey:@"keyToLookupString"];
```

See [this](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/10/03/iphone-programming-tutorial-savingretrieving-data-using-nsuserdefaults/) tutorial